# Confusion regarding the interpretation of the following proposition and the proof that is provided

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am reading a book on group theory and I frequently come across propositions that I am unsure of how to interpret (especially given the "author-provided" abridged proofs that frequently follow the stated propositions).

Here is an example proposition that I am currently struggling to understand given the nature of the subsequently provided proof:

[image: Proposition]

Here is the author's abridged proof:

[image: Provided Proof]

Given the structure of the proof, I am quite confused as to how I should interpret the last piece of the proposition: **"...is a bijection"**

Is this saying that given a map that sends elements of a subgroup to elements of a coset which is constructed from this aforementioned subgroup, **it is possible** to have a bijection? Or is this saying that we are **guaranteed** to have a bijection?

The part of the proof that makes me lean towards the first interpretation is the fact that the author assumes $\phi (h) = \phi (g) $...shouldn't I have to first prove that this IS the case rather than assume it to be true?

If I am **assuming this truth**, then certainly a better read on the proposition is: *then it is possible that the map is a bijection*

Any assistance is greatly appreciated...especially when it comes to generalizing how I should understand the language of this author's (and others) written propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific map which was defined **is** a bijection-this is a fact, without any "possible" things. What is a bijection? It is a function which is both injective and surjective. And the author proves that $\phi$ is indeed such a function. Injective means that $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$ happens only when $g=h$. So to prove $\phi$ is injective the author assumes that $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$ for $g,h\in H$ and he shows that this implie $g=h$. This is a standard way to prove a function is injective.

Comment: ohhhh, I see. So the key idea here is that it is certainly possible that some arbitrary map has the feature that $\phi (g) = \phi (h) $ but $g \neq h$. However, for this PARTICULAR map, if  $\phi (g) = \phi (h) $, then $g = h$ . Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. For this specific map $\phi(g)=\phi(h)$ always implies $g=h$.

Answer (score 1):

There is a map $\phi$ in the proposition and the proposition states that $\phi$ **is** a bijection between the sets $H$ and $xH$.

Comment: So the key idea here is that it is certainly possible that some arbitrary map has the feature that $\phi (g) = \phi (h) $ but $g \neq h$. However, for this PARTICULAR map, if  $\phi (g) = \phi (h) $, then $g = h$ . Is this correct?

Comment: Yes. That is what being injective means.